# Create an empty file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

For now I use

```
fs.openSync(filepath, 'a')
```

But it's a little tricky. Is there a 'standard' way to create an empty file in Node.js?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

If you want to force the file to be empty then you want to use the `'w'` flag instead:

```
var fd = fs.openSync(filepath, 'w');
```

That will truncate the file if it exists and create it if it doesn't.

Wrap it in an `fs.closeSync` call if you don't need the file descriptor it returns.

```
fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(filepath, 'w'));
```

Comment: fs.writeFileSync('empty.txt', '');

Comment: fs.appendFileSync('do_not_override.txt', '');

Comment: you may take a look here for more options than `w` flag https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags

Comment: is there a way to create multiple directories at once other than looping `mkdir`?? thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here's the async way, using `"wx"` so it fails on existing files.

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.open(path, "wx", function (err, fd) {
    // handle error
    fs.close(fd, function (err) {
        // handle error
    });
});
```

Comment: why would you want it to fail?

Comment: @NickSotiros so the file doesn't get overwritten, some use cases may want that.

Answer (score 11):

If you want it to be just like the UNIX touch I would use what you have `fs.openSync(filepath, 'a')` otherwise the 'w' will overwrite the file if it already exists and 'wx' will fail if it already exists.  But you want to update the file's mtime, so use 'a' and append nothing.