# Creating a file only if it doesn't exist in Node.js

Tags: node.js

We have a buffer we'd like to write to a file. If the file already exists, we need to increment an index on it, and try again. Is there a way to create a file only if it doesn't exist, or should I just stat files until I get an error to find one that doesn't exist already?

For example, I have files `a_1.jpg` and `a_2.jpg`. I'd like my method to try creating `a_1.jpg` and `a_2.jpg`, and fail, and finally successfully create `a_3.jpg`.

The ideal method would look something like this:

```
fs.writeFile(path, data, { overwrite: false }, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});
```

or like this:

```
fs.createWriteStream(path, { overwrite: false });
```

Does anything like this exist in node's `fs` library?

*EDIT*: My question isn't if there's a separate function that checks for existence. It's this: is there a way to create a file if it doesn't exist, in a single file system call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create an empty file in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809068/create-an-empty-file-in-nodejs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a file if it doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31195391/create-a-file-if-it-doesnt-already-exist)

Answer (score 107):

As your intuition correctly guessed, the naive solution with a pair of `exists / writeFile` calls is wrong. Asynchronous code runs in unpredictable ways. And in given case it is

- Is there a file `a.txt`? — No.
- (File `a.txt` gets created by another program)
- Write to `a.txt` if it's possible. — Okay.

But yes, we can do that in a single call. We're working with file system so it's a good idea to read developer manual on `fs`. And hey, [here's](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback) an interesting part.

> 'w' - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not
>   exist) or truncated (if it exists).
>
> 'wx' - Like 'w' but fails if path exists.

So all we have to do is just add `wx` to the `fs.open` call. But hey, we don't like `fopen`-like IO. Let's read on `fs.writeFile` a bit more.

> fs.readFile(filename[, options], callback)#
>
> filename String
>
> options Object
>
> > encoding String | Null default = null
> >
> > flag String default = 'r'
>
> callback Function

That `options.flag` looks promising. So we try

```
fs.writeFile(path, data, { flag: 'wx' }, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("It's saved!");
});
```

And it works perfectly for a single write. I guess this code will fail in some more bizarre ways yet if you try to solve your task with it. You have an atomary "check for `a_#.jpg` existence, and write there if it's empty" operation, but all the other `fs` state is not locked, and `a_1.jpg` file may spontaneously disappear while you're already checking `a_5.jpg`. Most[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_NTFS) file systems are no [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) databases, and the fact that you're able to do at least some atomic operations is miraculous. It's very likely that `wx` code won't work on some platform. So for the sake of your sanity, *use database, finally*.

#### Some more info for the suffering

Imagine we're writing something like [`memoize-fs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoize-fs) that caches results of function calls to the file system to save us some network/cpu time. Could we open the file for reading if it exists, and for writing if it doesn't, all in the single call? Let's take a funny look on those flags. After a while of mental exercises we can see that `a+` does what we want: if the file doesn't exist, it creates one and opens it both for reading and writing, and if the file exists it does so without clearing the file (as `w+` would). But now we cannot use it neither in `(smth)File`, nor in `create(Smth)Stream` functions. And that seems like a missing feature.

So feel free to file it as a feature request (or even a bug) to Node.js github, as lack of atomic asynchronous file system API is a drawback of Node. Though [don't expect](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/7593) changes any time soon.

Edit. I would like to link to articles by [Linus](https://lwn.net/Articles/326505/) and by [Dan Luu](https://danluu.com/file-consistency/) on why exactly you don't want to do anything smart with your `fs` calls, because the claim was left mostly not based on anything.

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu, this throws an error if the file exists.

Comment: @rhythnic Read the question.

Answer (score 40):

What about using the `a` option?

According to [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback):

> 'a+' - Open file for reading and appending. The file is created if it does not exist.

It seems to work perfectly with `createWriteStream`

Comment: This opens the file even if it exists, which isn't what I want unforunately.

Answer (score 12):

***This method is no longer recommended. fs.exists is deprecated. See comments.***

Here are some options:

1) Have **2 "fs" calls**. The first one is the "**fs.exists**" call, and the second is "**fs.write** / read, etc"

```
//checks if the file exists. 
//If it does, it just calls back.
//If it doesn't, then the file is created.
function checkForFile(fileName,callback)
{
    fs.exists(fileName, function (exists) {
        if(exists)
        {
            callback();
        }else
        {
            fs.writeFile(fileName, {flag: 'wx'}, function (err, data) 
            { 
                callback();
            })
        }
    });
}

function writeToFile()
{
    checkForFile("file.dat",function()
    {
       //It is now safe to write/read to file.dat
       fs.readFile("file.dat", function (err,data) 
       {
          //do stuff
       });
    });
}
```

2) Or **Create an empty file** first:

--- Sync:

```
//If you want to force the file to be empty then you want to use the 'w' flag:

var fd = fs.openSync(filepath, 'w');

//That will truncate the file if it exists and create it if it doesn't.

//Wrap it in an fs.closeSync call if you don't need the file descriptor it returns.

fs.closeSync(fs.openSync(filepath, 'w'));
```

--- ASync:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.open(path, "wx", function (err, fd) {
    // handle error
    fs.close(fd, function (err) {
        // handle error
    });
});
```

3) Or use "**touch**": https://github.com/isaacs/node-touch

Comment: **Note that fs.exists is deprecated and no longer recommended for use.** 
**From the [Node API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback)**:  
_checking if a file exists before opening it is an anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there. fs.exists() will be deprecated._

Answer (score 8):

Todo this in a single system call you can use the `fs-extra` npm module.
After this the file will have been created as well as the directory it is to be placed in.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const file = '/tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/file.txt'
fs.ensureFile(file, err => {
    console.log(err) // => null
});
```

Another way is to use [ensureFileSync](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/ensureFile-sync.md) which will do the same thing but synchronous.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const file = '/tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/file.txt'
fs.ensureFileSync(file)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to tell me if the file existed or was created by the operation - it just makes sure it exists after the operation, so I can't know if I should know write to it.

Comment: The fs-extra ensureFileSync function did the trick for me. Now I don't have to write the logic myself.

Answer (score 4):

With `async` / `await` and Typescript I would do:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs'

async function upsertFile(name: string) {
  try {
    // try to read file
    await fs.promises.readFile(name)
  } catch (error) {
    // create empty file, because it wasn't found
    await fs.promises.writeFile(name, '')
  }
}
```

Comment: readFile will throw for a number of different reasons, not just a missing file.  You should test `error.code === 'ENOENT'`.

Comment: In addition to @UpTheCreek's point, this is vulnerable to race conditions, plus unnecessarily reads the entire file if it does already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a synchronous way of doing it:

```js
try {
    await fs.truncateSync(filepath, 0);
} catch (err) {
    await fs.writeFileSync(filepath, "", { flag: "wx" });
}
```

If the file exists it will get truncated, otherwise it gets created if an error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
// Use the file system fs promises 
const {access} = require('fs/promises');

// File Exist returns true
// dont use exists which is no more!
const fexists =async (path)=> {  
    try {
      await access(path);
      return true;
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
  }


// Wrapper for your main program
  async function mainapp(){
  if( await fexists("./users.json")){
    console.log("File is here");
  } else { 
    console.log("File not here -so make one");
  }
}

// run your program
mainapp();
```

Just keep eye on your async - awaits so everthing plays nice.
hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
function writeFile(i){
    var i = i || 0;
    var fileName = 'a_' + i + '.jpg';
    fs.exists(fileName, function (exists) {
        if(exists){
            writeFile(++i);
        } else {
            fs.writeFile(fileName);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is similar to what I've done; I was hoping there was a way to create the file and check for existence in a single fs call.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. The file could be created in-between the calls to `fs.exists` and `fs.writeFile`.

Comment: @ebohlman Can you explain please? Here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349548/how-does-process-nexttick-keep-my-stack-from-blowing-up

Comment: Just to note here, @ebohlman's comment is not necessary, because `fs.exists` is already async and will reset the call stack.

Comment: @Steve File should be opened with [`wx` rights](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback). So the call looks like `fs.writeFile('path', {flag: 'wx'}, function (err, data) { ... })`.

Comment: A more complicated solution is needed if one needs to open file for reading if it exists, and open for writing if it doesn't (i.e. caching): `ax+`.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph could you please post this as an answer? It deserves more attention since it is obviously the better solution.

Comment: @JosefEngelfrost Done.