# Create a file if it doesn't already exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I would like to create a file `foobar`. However, if the user already has a file named `foobar` then I don't want to overwrite theirs. So I only want to create `foobar` if it doesn't exist already.

At first, I thought that I should do this:

```
fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
  if(exists) {
    // Create file
  }
  else {
    console.log("Refusing to overwrite existing", filename);
  }
});
```

However, looking at the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_exists_path_callback) for `fs.exists`, it reads:

> fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons.
>   There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code.
>
> In particular, checking if a file exists before opening it is an
>   anti-pattern that leaves you vulnerable to race conditions: another
>   process may remove the file between the calls to fs.exists() and
>   fs.open(). Just open the file and handle the error when it's not
>   there.
>
> fs.exists() will be deprecated.

Clearly the node developers think my method is a bad idea. Also, I don't want to use a function that will be deprecated.

How can I create a file without writing over an existing one?

Comment: it tells you: open the file and handle the error (or lack thereof)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a file only if it doesn't exist in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899061/creating-a-file-only-if-it-doesnt-exist-in-node-js)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Just open the file and handle the error when it's not there.

Try something like:

```
function createFile(filename) {
  fs.open(filename,'r',function(err, fd){
    if (err) {
      fs.writeFile(filename, '', function(err) {
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
          console.log("The file was saved!");
      });
    } else {
      console.log("The file exists!");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
fs.closeSync(fs.openSync('/var/log/my.log', 'a'))
```

Answer (score 6):

```js
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

fs.readFile(path).catch(() =>
    fs.writeFile(path, content)
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to write data to this file later, you can use `fs.appendFile('message.txt', 'data to append', 'utf8', callback);`.

> Asynchronously append data to a file, **creating the file if it does not yet exist**. Data can be a string or a buffer.

[Node file system documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback).