# Creating a file of certain size on the go in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to create a file of certain size (20MB) in the cypress test.

I don't want to include a real file in the fixtures as it would clutter my repository.

I can't use an environment file as this would be run locally and on CI. It needs to be platform independent.

Is there a way I can do this in the test without the usage of system scripts? Like in this question [Creating an empty file of a certain size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433241/creating-an-empty-file-of-a-certain-size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which is working for me with the use of `Cypress.Buffer` without creating a physical file on disk:

```
const moreThanFiftyMb = 50000000 + 1
const bigFile = Cypress.Buffer.alloc(moreThanFiftyMb)
bigFile.write("X", moreThanFiftyMb)

cy.get("#file-manager-drop-target").selectFile({
  contents: bigFile,
  fileName: 'more-than50mb.txt',
  mimeType: 'text/plain'
});`
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by using cy.task.

in my test

> cy.task('createFile', 'fileName').then( .... test code)

in plugins/index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
on('task', {
   createFile(fileName) {
      return new Promise((done) => {
         const fh = fs.openSync(config.fileName, 'w');
         fs.writeSync(fh, 'ok', Math.max(0, DESIRED_SIZE));
         fs.closeSync(fh);
         done(true);
      });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, using TypeScript and inspired by @Zoidy's answer, this is what I'm doing:

```
// cypress.config.ts
import fs from "fs";
import { MY_MAX_FILE_SIZE } from "utils/api/constants";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on) {
      on("task", {
        createFile(fileName: string) {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const dir = path.dirname(fileName);

            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
              fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
            }

            const fileHandler = fs.openSync(fileName, "w");

            fs.writeSync(fileHandler, "dummy", MY_MAX_FILE_SIZE + 1);

            fs.closeSync(fileHandler);

            resolve(true);
          });
        },
      });
    },
  },
});
```

```
// cypress/e2e/myTest.cy.ts
describe('My Test', () => {
  it('shows error when dropped file exceeds max-size', () => {
    const fileName = 'cypress/fixtures/generated/tooBig.xlsx';
    cy.task('createFile', fileName).then(() => {
      // drag'n'drop file
      cy.get('[data-testid=uploadArea]').selectFile(fileName, {
        action: 'drag-drop',
      });

      // assert file was not added
      cy.get('#table').children().should('have.length', 1);

      // assert Error is shown
      cy.get('notification-host')
        .find('notification[variant=error]')
        .contains(
          "File is too large (max. 1 MB). Please upload a file that's smaller than 1 MB.",
        );
    });
  });
});
```

To get rid of the generated files, I have added a `pretest` and `posttest`. You could think that adding just `posttest` would be enough, but if you are running tests in any way other than `npm run test`, the `posttest`-command is not automatically triggered, so for example through the UI, you'd end up with a bunch of auto generated files not cleaned-up.

```json
// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "rimraf cypress/fixtures/generated",
    "test": "npm run cypress:run",
    "posttest": "rimraf cypress/fixtures/generated"
  }
}
```

Additionally, I added the dir to my `.gitignore` to avoid it ever being added to the  source control panel of my IDE:

```
// .gitignore
cypress/fixtures/generated
```